# How to overcome subtle conflicts between Bootstrap.js and Avada WordPress theme

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We have been developing a WordPress website using the Avada WordPress theme. This site is integrated with WHMCS using a premium WHMCS template called Responsio+.

The problem seems to be a conflict between Avada and bootstrap.js which is used by Responsio+. For a quick view of this problem you can go to the author's [Responsio+ Demo for Avada](http://demo.whmcsconnect.com/wordpress/avada/modals/). Click the `Modal Button` button and observe the popup immediately disappear.

My suspicion is that Avada started with Bootstrap CSS/JS code early on since I see Avada selectors of `bs.modal`, etc.

Since I am not willing to give up the Avada theme, and I would like to use Responsio+ as well, does anyone see how I might include Responsio+'s main wrapper class/id in all of bootstrap.js event trigger selectors so they quit firing on Avada modal popups? I believe Responsio+ uses only bootstrap.min.js.

There are other conflicts, like in the toggles shortcode, but I'm sure the solution will be the same.

**EDIT**

All of Avada's modal popups have a wrapper of `<div class="fusion-modal ... >`. All of the Bootstrap modal popups are wrapped with Responsio+'s `<div id="imsync-wrapper">` wrapper.

My thought is that there is some way to slightly modify the bootstrap.js event trigger selectors to only fire on Responsio+'s modals.

I don't like modifying a dist file like this, but it's either that or take several steps backwards. I didn't think it would be major to add #imsync-wrapper to bootstrap.js modal code, but maybe it's not so simple. Thing is, I'm not exactly positive where this change would be most effective and I think I am asking for a Bootstrap pro to weigh in.

Also, I tried putting the modal plugin in noConflict() mode. Placing the following before `</head>` doesn't seem to help:

```
<script>
    var bsModal = jQuery.fn.modal.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: Nobody here is going to go through a whole theme to debug it for you. Report as bug to author and look for support from there

Comment: I don't want to debug a theme, thx. The Responsio+ author is nonresponsive completely. The fix is not to 'debug' every theme, the fix (hack even) is to fix Responsio+'s bootstrap dependency. I somewhat doubt you understand the potential fix or you wouldn't have commented like this and downvoted the question. I don't like having to make any modification for this, but it's the only way if I am going to run it. As for Avada - this isn't their problem. It's Responsio's - but the author don't respond.

Comment: This site is intended to help resolve specific code problems. That means providing the problematic code in question itself. Links to a complex page demo full of numerous scripts don't meet that. Sure i could fix it...but that might require hours to find the conflicts in the first place ...which nobody here is going to do

Comment: Best suggestion is start backing out code until you find the conflict ... then work with the part of the code that causes it

Comment: I have upvoted your question because I know the answer. Perhaps, if you asked it in more generic form it would be easier to help.

Comment: It was a difficult question to form. The whiner comments are from someone who polices SO for posts to downvote and complain about. I'm not perfect, but thank you again for taking the time to straighten this out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by bootstrap.js included twice on your page. To resolve it you may use the code I posted here: [How to avoid double inclusion of Bootstrap.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077849/wordpress-how-to-avoid-bootstrap-js-conflict-in-a-theme-and-a-plugin/35077850#35077850)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking bootstrap just wasn't compatible with my theme, but this fix makes it all good. :)