# How to avoid double inclusion of Bootstrap.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

We've been developing a Wordpress theme and stumbled on a weird problem. A popup displayed by bootstrap.js appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears. After thorough research I have figured out that the problem is caused by a plugin which also uses bootstrap.js. Two bootstrap.js were loaded, one from our theme and another from the plugin. How to avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to check if bootstrap.js is already enqueued. I've added the following to functions.php of the theme:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    // Check if bootstrap is already there
    $bootstrap_enqueued = FALSE;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->registered as $script ) {
        if ((stristr($script->src, 'bootstrap.min.js') !== FALSE or
             stristr($script->src, 'bootstrap.js') != FALSE) and
            wp_script_is($script->handle, $list = 'enqueued')) {

            $bootstrap_enqueued = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$bootstrap_enqueued) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '2015', true );
}

// Note the last parameter. It's important to be the last in the list of hooks
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts', PHP_INT_MAX );`
```

Comment: Hello. I am having the same issue. Can you provide some instruction for me please? Where is this put in the functions.php? What do I have to rename? I am using Avada theme and having an issue with Formidable Pro Modal Popup. Formidable Pro has wp-content/themes/Avada/assets/js/bootstrap.js Formidable Pro wp-content/plugins/formidable-modal/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: In this case you either have to update functions.php in Avada theme or in Formidable popup. There, find references to bootstrap.min.js and delete them or comment out. Then add the code I posted here. Though, please note, any updates from Avada or Formidable will overwrite your changes. It's better to contact developers of that software and ask them to include this code to their software.